# Populate the list of assignees of an issue in github

Tags: github, issue-tracking

I have four *contributors* in my github project.
I create an issue I would like to assign it to a particular contributor but the list shows only two contributors.

How do I add the other persons? Simply typing his name does not work.

Comment: Do all of your collaborators have read access to the code?

Comment: @chris the repository is public so I assume they have read access : https://github.com/theworldisnotflat/shriveling_world

Comment: Which collaborators are you seeing? Which are you unable to add?

Comment: @Chris I see myself and CodeInLight in the drop down list but not the two other, kaktus40 for instance

Comment: Are you sure these people are all [_collaborators_](https://help.github.com/en/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository)? (The repository maybe public, but its settings aren't.) Just because a person is a [_contributor_](https://github.com/theworldisnotflat/shriveling_world/graphs/contributors) doesn't make them a _collaborator_.

Comment: Thanks @Chris I believe this is on the way to be solved: I have declared the _contributors_ as _collaborators_, and now I must wait for their approval, and then I guess I will be able to assign them to an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue can only have assigned *collaborators* and simple *contributors* cannot be assigned.

To solve this issue I had to invite the *contributors* to accept becoming *collaborators*.

The [doc states](https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp/wiki/Contributors-vs-Collaborators) that :

- Contributor: A contributor is someone from the outside not on the core development team of the project that wants to contribute some changes to a project.
- Collaborator: A collaborator is someone on the core development team of the project and has commit access to the main repository of the project.